# How to catch hold of a uploaded file in angular, as we hold the text boxes values?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have five page application, in which user will upload a file and the same file need to be populated in other pages on load.

How can it be done in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ngx-file-drop`](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop).

Then if you want to keep the file for other views just put it into [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

**Typescript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { UploadEvent, UploadFile } from 'ngx-file-drop';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 public files: UploadFile[] = [];

  public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {
    // set files
    this.files = event.files;

    // save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('files', { files : this.files })
  }

  getFile() {
    return localStorage.getItem('files');
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <file-drop headertext="Drop files here" 
               (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)">
    </file-drop>
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="files?.length > 0">
    <hello *ngFor="let file of files" [file]="file"></hello>
</ng-container>
```

[Here is a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvguii)